# How to fold "public static" class fields in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Some of the classes I'm working on have 50+ "public static" fields. Is it possible to fold those fields in Eclipse? I searched so and Google, but so far best I got is putting them inside a block with {}, but that's not allowed for "public static".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting available, but an alternative might be to move all of them to the bottom...

There is also the coffee-bytes code folding plugin from Yoxos marketplace, maybe this will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the info, it's working now.. couldn't find coffe-byte plugin from Yoxos, then found older version from googlecode but User Defined Regions didn't work (for Eclipse 4.2.0), and then finally found working version from [link](http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html).